# Django relative path syntax

Tags: python, django

In this django project, the views.py in the 'basket' folder needs to import the 'Product' class from the 'store' folder.  These two folders are at the same level, from the top folder.

But 'from store.models import Product' gives an 'unresolved reference' error.  I've tried several permutations, to no avail.

Please help.

I've tried using one dot, and two dots before 'store'.  With two dots it goes too far up in the folders structure, with one it still shows 'unresolved reference for the 'store' folder.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi8wY.png)

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i76756930/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should mark `Final` as the source directory.